# Is there a way to view history timeline for entire project in TFS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visualization

I would like to view the branching history for the entire project in TFS 2010. This has been possible in all other version control systems I've used (Git, Mercurial, SVN). Something like this:  http://web.uvic.ca/~arasbm/ProjectSummery/linuxBranches.png

I know it is possible to view the timeline for a specific changeset (*Track Changeset -> Timeline Tracking*), or viewing the entire history (*View History*) in simple list. I basically want those two functions combined. Is this possible in TFS 2010?

Answer (score 1):

you cannot show visualized history like you're asking in tfs2010

Answer (score 0):

In Source Control Explorer, hit CTRL+G. This will bring up the Find Changesets dialog. It is probably the closest thing to this sort of feature.

This might be worth a [read](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hakane/archive/2009/05/19/enable-branch-visualization-in-upgraded-team-projects-tfs-2010-beta1.aspx)

Comment: How is that different from the _View History_ option? It looks like it is showing the same thing albeit in a different dialog. Or am I missing something?